# How to create UIStackView from code correctly

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I can't understand why this layout won't render the way i need it. Completing the requirement on android with linearlayouts should be equivalent to this?

What i get:

[image: What i get]

What i need:

[image: What i need]

My code:

```
        // my stackview only renders at all if i pass any height > 0 && width > 0, 
        // but i would love this to be as small as possible, given that all children 
        // are rendered.
        var stackView = new UIStackView(View.Frame);
        stackView.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical;
        stackView.Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.Fill;

        foreach (var deviceVm in devices)
        {
            // i would prefer this not to have a rect parameter and scale as needed.
            var descriptionLabel = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Bounds.Width, 20));
            descriptionLabel.Text = deviceVm.Description;
            descriptionLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Blue;
            descriptionLabel.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
            stackView.AddArrangedSubview(descriptionLabel);
        }

        // i assume this should make it as small as possible, as big as necessary?
        stackView.SizeToFit();

        var scrollView = new UIScrollView(View.Frame);
        scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
        scrollView.AddSubview(stackView);
        View.AddSubview(scrollView);
```

Can someone spot a mistake i am doing here? Am i configuring the StackView incorrectly or is this control not the equivalent of LinearLayout(android) / StackPanel(wpf) ?

PS: Sorry for eye cancer paint pictures.

Comment: You can try adding the descriptionLabel.sizeToFit() while creating the labels to keep the height to the minimum?

Comment: @Prav No change in rendering behaviour unfortunately

Comment: Please try descriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO. i hope this helps